# Is it acceptable to have multiple producers on different servers writing to the same topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

We have two different Producer applications running on two different servers. Is it a good idea to have both Producers write to the same Kafka topic? Any performance issues expected?

Answer (score 3):

Having multiple producers that write to the same topic is absolutely fine. There is no need to worry about performance.

Note, there is no ordering guarantee for messages written by different producers.